# is event.pageX null check needed?

Tags: javascript

I have this code to get the mouse location.
I wonder if there is actual need for:

```
if (event.pageX != null)
```

Are there any cases where `event.pageX` is `null`?

Also do I need the `event || window.event;`?

```
function handleMouseMove(event) {

    event = event || window.event;

    if (event.pageX != null) {
        key = event.pageX * event.pageY;
    };
}
```

What if I rewrite the code like this?

```
function handleMouseMove(event) {
    key = event.pageX * event.pageY;      
}
```

Comment: `event = event || window.event` is a polyfill for ancient browsers.

Comment: Based on the event polyfill, targeting IE where `pageX` and `pageY` don't exist, as opposed to `pageYOffset`/`pageXOffset`.  Checking pageX for explicit "null" is strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the null check is unnecessary. As Assafi has mentioned `pageX` is only `null` on initial rendering. Since `pageX` is wrapped in a function it's unlikely it'll ever be called when `pageX` is `null`. [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/mqcw8r4s/5/) a visual example from the Mozilla docs. We also want to keep the `||` statement to support older browsers.

Overall your code could be written as:

```
function handleMouseMove(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    key = event.pageX * event.pageY;      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If, for some reason, the listener triggers before the window is finished loading, then `event.pageX` will be `null` and the function will return an error. Although you are using a mouse event listener, which is unlikely to trigger before the window's `onload` function, it is better to check if the `pageX` is null.

Bottom Line: Better safe than sorry.